# What is the matter distribution function for the FLRW metric?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, statistical-mechanics

For a non-relativistic gas we have the [Maxwell Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution)

For a relativistic gas we have the [Maxwell Juttner distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93J%C3%BCttner_distribution#)

What is the phase space distribution function for the FLRW metric (for our universe)?

Comment: I can't see FLRW changing anything. Even if you modify relativity for a massive particle to $\beta=a\tanh w,\,\gamma=\cosh w$ in terms of a rapidity $w\in\Bbb R$, all that does is insert the blue factor in $d^3u=\color{blue}{a}\gamma^2\beta d\gamma d\Omega$. Unitarity will delete it again anyway.

Comment: @J.G. I see. Is this solvable then? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/49520/order-of-magnitude-of-this-phase-space-invariant

Comment: That question asks for an empirical value, but theoretically $R$ is the mean of $1/p_0$ for MJ, i.e.$$\frac{1}{mc^2}\frac{\int_1^\infty\gamma\beta\exp(-mc^2\gamma/(k_BT))d\gamma}{\int_1^\infty\gamma^2\beta\exp(-mc^2\gamma/(k_BT))d\gamma}=\frac{1}{mc^2}\frac{\int_0^\infty\sinh^2w\exp\left(-\frac{mc^2}{k_BT}\cosh w\right)dw}{\int_0^\infty\sinh^2w\cosh w\exp\left(-\frac{mc^2}{k_BT}\cosh w\right)dw}.$$

Comment: @J.G. I'm confused. How is it my question is asking for the solution of one integral and yours is using $2$ integrals?

Comment: When a PDF is proportional to $f$, the mean of $g$ is the ratio of two definite integrals, viz. $\int fgdx/\int fdx$. You can just define $k:=\int fdx,\,F:=f/k$, then write it as $\int Fgdx$, but I didn't work out the normalization.

Answer (score 3):

In cosmology we consider matter to be (on really big scales) homogeneous and isotropic so for the FLRW metric and in general the energy density is taken to be
$$\rho_i = g_i \int \frac{\text{d}^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}f_i(\vec{x},\vec{p})E(p)$$
(in natural units) with $g_i$ the degeneracy of the species, for bosons we take the Bose-Einstein distribution $f_{BE}(p)$ (no $\vec{x}$ or $\hat{p}$ dependence due to the homogeneity assumption) and for fermions such as electrons the Fermi-Dirac distributions $f_{FD}(p)$. So in short just the Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein distributions.

(The number of phase space elements in $\text{d}^3x\text{d}^3p$ is $\frac{\text{d}^3x\text{d}^3p}{(2\pi \hbar)^3}$ multiplied by the distribution function $f(p)$, for more info see Dodelson: Modern Cosmology chapter 2.3)

Note: Here $\vec{p}$ is proper momentum which goes like $a^{-1}$ in FLRW

Comment: Equation 3.31b : http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2012/1203.1.K.pdf

Comment: This ^ seems to suggest a different expression. I don't think yours is covariant.